# I am working with a large dataset, RStudio slows down and goes back to normal after I restart it

Tags: r

Is there a another way to get RStudio running at normal speed once it starts lagging other than having to restart?

I am working with large datasets and understand that is expected.  However a simple command like `2000 + 2000` starts running with a lag, and once I restart RStudio the speed goes back to normal.  I think that RStudio starts running with a lag once if I run a command that asks R to display 1000's of entries.  It is annoying as heck and would appreciate some feedback and comments, Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes clearing the console with CTRL + L helps speed things back up.

Comment: That worked, thanks

Comment: Also, in your scripts when you are previewing or loading large files, do something to them then attempt to work on smaller objects, write `gc()` into your scripts to garbage collect any duplicates of the data frame created during processing.  (And if you loaded a huge set, did some work extracted a smaller set and moved on, run `rm("name_of_big_set")` and `gc()`.  It can make a substantial difference to remove the large set and garbage collect. R works in live memory...managing it can be trick~